# ubuntu grub rewrite mbr on second drive constantly

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I got two physical drives on my PC, first for Windows 7, second for Ubuntu.

First one with Windows 7 is default boot drive in BIOS.

My idea is to have Windows MBR on Windows 7 drive and GRUB on Ubuntu drive

so I will be able to take off second drive without affecting Windows boot-ability.

Problem: each time I'm doing "apt upgrade" to get new kernel Ubuntu rewrites MBR on first drive with GRUB.

It's really annoying and nonsense. How can I stop it?

Comment: As far i know ,thats the default behavior of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find out on which HDD Ubuntu is installed. You can use `Disks` to examine your drives, open the Dash and type `disks` in the search-box, then just click on the icon which is labeled `Disks`. In `Disks` you will be able to see on which drive Windows is installed and on which drive Ubuntu is installed.

Then open a terminal ( `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`) and run the command

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX`
```

Replace **X** with the correct letter you found out in the first step. Don't add any number to the command, for example, if you install Grub to `sdb1`, Grub will be installed to the partition boot record of the first partition on the second drive, not to the MBR of the second drive!

In the BIOS change the boot-order to this drive.